# Can't read files on network shared folder [webbapp is over tomcat as a service]

Tags: java, tomcat, service, file-copying, local-network

I've a web application on Tomcat 7.0.57 on Windows 8.1 **running it as a service**, that is instructed to copy a file on a locally network shared directory, for example \\Network_machine\Shared_folder, but it's not able to do so.

I am able to access the shared folder in windows explorer without any authentication, as it has **permission to read for everyone**. The following code is checking for the directory exist:

```
  String sourceURL = this.servletContext.getInitParameter("sourceURL");
  log.debug("---------->Source reports directory : " + sourceURL);
  File sourceDir = new File(sourceURL);
  log.debug("---------->Source directory exists : "+sourceDir.exists());
  if (sourceDir.exists()) {
    String files[] = sourceDir.list();
    log.debug("----------> Total files in source dir :" + files.length);
    List<String> newFiles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(files));
    newFiles.removeAll(processedFiles);
    log.debug("----------> Latest files in source dir :" + newFiles.size());
    File file = null;
    if (newFiles.size() > 0) {
      for (String fileName : newFiles) {
        file = new File(sourceURL + Constants.FILE_SEP + fileName);
        latestSourceFiles.add(file);
      }
    }
  } else {
    log.debug("Source reports directory " + sourceURL + " is not found");
  }
```

Additional Info:

log - Source directory exists is returning 'FALSE'.

Comment: You will need to map a drive... So in windows `net use * \\server\share` or use a mount (run the net use in a command prompt)

Comment: What account is the service running under? Are you sure that account can access network resources?

Comment: @MarkWagoner .. the service is running under LocalSystem account.

Comment: @KennethClark .. Mapping a drive is also not working, I have already tried that option.

Comment: You will need to ensure the permissions on the Share and File permissions on the directory are correct for the user context. I.E does the Application Server user have permission to access the share and the contents.

Comment: Try temporarily changing the login account to something that you know works (from Explorer, for example). That way you can at least rule out a permissions problem.

Comment: The source folder is a shared folder on network and has read permission for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kenneth says, you need to map the shared folder to a drive and then write directly to that drive.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive

Comment: mapping a drive is not helping...as tomcat is running as a service with localsystem as account.

Comment: I will try it later, but can't you change the account to run the tomcat service?

http://superuser.com/questions/301864/run-tomcat-service-as-different-user-on-windows-7

Comment: Guillermo Gefaell...It Worked ! But my requirement is it should run under localsystem account, if so can you please guide me. Thanks Once again.

Comment: Weird. I'm also developing over tomcat 7 and my app also has to write to a shared folder, mapped to an unit. Started Tomcat as a service with default acoount and everything went fine. Review the security of your mapped unit. (Right click on unit -> properties -> security)

Comment: My app has to copy/read files from shared folder on windows server 2008  to myApp/WEB-INF/tempFolder/, issue it is not able to find the path if the tomcat server is running as a service   under LocalSystem account, if I key user credential into account its copying files perfectly as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I think i can't help you further. The only reason i can think of to the service not being able to read the folder are the security settings of Windows on that folder. Have you tried to edit them?

Comment: I did edit the security settings of the shared folder on the network machine, the folder has permission to READ for EVERYONE,  but did not help...i am try to fix it...keep you posted about the solution.....anyways thanq very much for your extended support  @Guillermo